# DateTime System.FormatException in XML Serializable c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to read  the data from an XML.
Every thing is good except for a date field. When ever the date field is null , I am getting Exception

> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
>   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags
>   kinds)    at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s,
>   XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToDateTime(String
>   value)

Here is my XML

```
<TRANSACTION>
    <TRANSACTION_ID></TRANSACTION_ID>
    <MERCHANT_ACC_NO>02700701354375000964</MERCHANT_ACC_NO>
    <TXN_STATUS>F</TXN_STATUS>
    <TXN_SIGNATURE777779</TXN_SIGNATURE>
    <TXN_SIGNATURE2>877888C</TXN_SIGNATURE2>
    <TRAN_DATE></TRAN_DATE>
    <MERCHANT_TRANID>151019OHOOZS1</MERCHANT_TRANID>
    <RESPONSE_CODE>3009</RESPONSE_CODE>
    <RESPONSE_DESC>Unable to find the transaction record!</RESPONSE_DESC>
    <AUTH_ID></AUTH_ID>
    <AUTH_DATE></AUTH_DATE>
    <CAPTURE_DATE></CAPTURE_DATE>
    <SALES_DATE></SALES_DATE>
    <VOID_REV_DATE></VOID_REV_DATE>
  </TRANSACTION>
</TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>
```

Now my  class

```
[Serializable]
    public class MaybankeBPGResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("TRANSACTION_ID")]
        public string MaybankeBPGTxnId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("MERCHANT_TRANID")]
        public string MerchantTxnId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValueAttribute(typeof(System.DateTime), "1901-01-01")]
        [XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
        public DateTime? AuthDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RESPONSE_CODE")]
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

I suspect the AuthDate  element is causing the problem  when the XML value is null.

Comment: Can you use modify the XML? If so `<AUTH_DATE />` might work.

Comment: do a simple google search on the following `C# [DefaultValueAttribute(typeof(System.DateTime),` notice how many examples come up in the search results perhaps change it to look like the following for example `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "")]`

Comment: Cant modify the XML @MikeH

Comment: @MethodMan , tried  `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "")]` , but exception still stays

Comment: Can you treat the value as a string and then use a property in your program to convert it when you need?

Comment: can you show the full `XML` looks like you are missing `<TRANSACTION_RESPONSE>`

Comment: @MethodMan, I have shown only the snippet of the xml , because that was a big one .   Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an intermediate property like this?

```
[XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
public string? stringAuthDate { get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime AuthDate
{
  get
  {
    DateTime dt;
    if (stringAuthDate.HasValue && DateTime.TryParse(stringAuthDate.Value, out dt))
      return dt;
    else
      return DateTime.MinValue;
  }
  set
  {
    stringAuthDate = value.ToShortDateString();   
  }
}
```

Comment: This has given me the light to the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the XML is invalid, at least as far as data types go. As the error message indicates the date in the XML is an empty string. 
The xml fragment  indicates the value of the elemtn AUTH_DATE is an empty string, not a null value.
If you want a null value, then you need .

You have a couple of solutions, the easiest and dirtiest being:
- Add a property used to capture the data as a raw string
- Modify the existing property to parse the data from this new property

```
[Serializable]
public class MaybankeBPGResponse
{
    [XmlElement("TRANSACTION_ID")]
    public string MaybankeBPGTxnId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("MERCHANT_TRANID")]
    public string MerchantTxnId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValueAttribute(typeof(System.DateTime), "1901-01-01")]
    [XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
    [EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public DateTime? AuthDateForSerialization { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AuthDate { 
        get {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthDateForSerialization) ? null : DateTime.ParseExact(AuthDateForSerialization, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set {
            AuthDateForSerialization = value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : String.Empty;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("RESPONSE_CODE")]
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback.
Based on the comments and  answers provided, i added a new property to capture the TRAN_DATE response as a string and convert it to date in   the code . here is the snippet

```
  [Serializable]
    public class MaybankeBPGResponse
   { 
    public DateTime? AuthDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TRAN_DATE")]
     public string AuthDateXML { get; set; }

   }
```

In the reading part , following modification is added

```
using (TextReader xmlreader = new StringReader(responseData))
 {
   QueryResponse value = (QueryResponse)serializer.Deserialize(xmlreader);
   result = value.transaction;

  DateTime autDate = DateTime.MinValue;

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AuthDateXML))
   {
    DateTime.TryParseExact(result.AuthDateXML, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out autDate);
     result.AuthDate = autDate;
   }
}
```